# Form.Location must be set twice

Tags: c#, winforms, xna-4.0

I'm writing a C# app (XNA to be specific) and I'm having some very strange behavior when trying to set the window location. The first time I set the location, it places it in a weird place (always the same) but if I set it again, even on the next line, it works.

This is the code I'm using. The initial values in Location are 657, 286. After attempting to set it to 1920, 300, the position becomes 2257, 314. If I run the set again, it correctly updates the position to 1920, 300.

I've tried a full clean and rebuild and tried running in both Debug and Release. I've also tried putting some code before this line just to attempt to rule out a timing issue. I'm totally stumped here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var form = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle( this.Window.Handle );
form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point( 1920, 300 );
```

Comment: These are not sane values unless you spent a lot of money on your screen.  The Form class *will* fight back when you try to send it off the screen.

Comment: Your comment did put me down a train of thought. It seems that it is related to showing it on the second monitor. Is there maybe something in the form that says what monitor it is displayed on? That would explain why it would need to be set twice; the first moves it to the monitor with some default position and the second actually works to set the position to what I want. I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: Yes, the form is aware of what screen it is on.  Use Screen.FromControl and Screen.WorkingArea to find a valid location and size.

Comment: Sadly, this has turned up nothing. As far as I can tell, I am doing this the correct way for trying to position a form on a second monitor. You just figure out the absolute value in screen space and set that as the location.

Answer (score 0):

To set the location of the form try this:

```
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1920, 300)
```

Note that this assumes the form you are trying to reposition is the parent object of the method you are calling.

Comment: That won't work for XNA. I'm calling this from the Game class which does not inherit from Form. The method I use above should be giving me the correct form.

Comment: I see.  Well, when are you attempting to set the form's visibility?  I know that setting the position before the `Form.Shown` event is raised can produce interesting errors in positioning the form.

Comment: Just tried putting the code inside of an if statement in the Update call. I waited until the game was fully running and visible before putting down a breakpoint and then manually executing the code. Still didn't work, although the random position on the screen that it chose is different (2300,600).